# Make PC sleep without power

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I have standard PC (not laptop) with Windows 10 that sometimes needs to be transportable. I would like to have such feature like sleep. But I can't supply power during transportation.

Is it possible somehow stay in sleep mode without power?

Comment: Without a battery, you will not be able to put a desktop computer to sleep. If you can enable hibernation, that might work. Test it. You can change a battery in a laptop while hibernated.

Comment: "Sleep" by definition requires power. However, most PCs can _hibernate_, which appears to meet your need. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/shut-down-sleep-or-hibernate-your-pc-2941d165-7d0a-a5e8-c5ad-8c972e8e6eff and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/disable-and-re-enable-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

If you can't supply power during transport "sleep" is not possible. Howerver your could buy a UPS (uninterruptible power source). This is basically a battery that can be attached to a regular PC. It should be enough to keep the S3 state and they come in different form factors and capacities.

Alternatively as suggested by John you could use Hibernate (also called "suspend to disk").

Hybernate and Sleep are actually called [Power States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_states) S3 and S4:

- S3, commonly referred to as Sleep: This state is where all system context is lost, except for RAM. RAM maintains power, and will generally allow you to quickly return to what you were doing before the system was put in Sleep.
- S4, referred to as Hibernation: The final sleep state is when your system goes into hibernation. This is when it’s in its lowest power setting, which also means it takes a long time to wake. Power is cut off from everything, including peripherals and any external hard drives. While it does take a much longer time to return to what you were doing, this state makes it so that you are losing no power whatsoever.

[Source](https://www.techjunkie.com/power-management-states-s-state-p-state/)

Comment: S4 is also called "Suspend to Disk" which makes it clear how it works.

Comment: good point, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Somewhat offtopic but I have a desktop on a desk with wheels that needs to change location often throughout the day and the only viable solution was to get a UPS (Uninterruptible Power Supply). Even Hibernating, which saves your state, was a hustle before that. Not to mention the amount of times it has saved me due to power outages. The most inexpensive ones run for under $50 online and will provide 10 to 30 min power depending on your setup. For me it's totally worth the investment.

Comment: what's the point of this answer? this is exactly what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Albin based on your comment after 2 weeks, I don't think you have the capacity to understand the point of my comment even if explained it to you...

Comment: If you contribution is a comment (as you state yourself by saying "the point of my comment") you should delete it and add it as such, meaning: as a comment, not an answer! This is besides the point that your answer is extremely rude ("I don't think you (...) understand (...) even if I explained it to you") - are you being serious?